# Iot hub service fetches old data when started

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am sending data from simulated client to iot hub. Initially iot hub receives the data very well. But now whenever iot hub starts It first fetch old data every time (and its same every time) and then starts receiving the new data if it is being sent by simulated device.

My application structure is like

`Iot device -------> Iot hub --------> Stream Analytics ---------> Event hub ----Triggers Function----> Azure Function`

Comment: Sounds like Stream Analytics is re-started from the start? When you start Stream Analytics you specify what date and time you want to start from. IoT Hub stores the data even after you have consumed it. If you start reading data from start, you'll get old data again.

Comment: But for my case its opposite scenario. Iot hub is consuming from device not from Stream. Stream is input to data coming from Iot hub.

Comment: see what @juunas suggests, IoT hub is always active but when retrieving messages one has to specify a starting point, otherwise a client by default starts from the oldest message present.